# generic .htaccess URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to make the following .htaccess file more generic, so that i don't have to modifie it each time i add a new directory with the service files?

The foldername is always the prefix of the service file in the folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ property/PropertyService.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ property/PropertyService.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ property/PropertyService.php [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^pitch/(.*)$ pitch/PitchService.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^pitch/(.*)$ pitch/PitchService.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^pitch/(.*)$ pitch/PitchService.php [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That .htaccess doesn't work anyway, as the destination matches the request regex. Error: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects [...]`

Comment: The given .htaccess works for me on MacOSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, but it should only work well on Windows due to case-insensitivity. To be specific, capturing the first segment (`property`, for example) and passing it to the filename causes Apache to look for, in this case, `property/propertyService.php`. Due to the lower-case `p`, Unix-based systems would not find the file.

Nonetheless, this should point you in the right direction.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^.]+)$ /$1/$1Service.php?request=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^.]+)$ /$1/$1Service.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you are happy with making the filename camelCase, then this will work perfectly for you. You could also switch to snake_case: `property/property_service.php`

Comment: I made the filename camelCase and removed the first slash in the new URL. Now all works fine :). Thanks for your help! Also the [OR] makes it more read and refactorable.